# Wireless-N Access Point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I'm looking to purchase a new AP, and found a decent value TP-Link on Amazon which is a Wireless-N Point. None of my wireless users actually utilize the  N band, they are all on G but I am looking to upgrade them soon. This is just a SOHO environment.

My understanding is correct that a Wireless N access point will still support clients on B/G etc? N is backwards compatible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many do, I've never seen one which doesn't. Most will list their capabilities as 802.11b/g/n which specifies all three standards.